# ld: library not found for -lstdc++.6

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode10

After updating Xcode Version to 10.0 beta start getting "ld: library not found for -lstdc++.6" error. same code working fine in Xcode 9.2

Also updated macOS to 10.13.5

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The quick solution is to copy all libstdc++.* file from old Xcode(9.4) to new Xcode(10.x)

For device :

cp /Applications/Xcode9.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.* /Applications/Xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/

For Simulator :

cp /Applications/Xcode9.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.* /Applications/Xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/

Comment: Download older version and try this, or find another source for these files.

Comment: This is a hack, not the answer.

Answer (score 14):

You'll have this issue when targeting iOS App. It's stated in the Release note:

> **Deprecation Notices**:
>
> **Building with libstdc++ was deprecated with Xcode 8 and is not
>   supported in Xcode 10 when targeting iOS**. C++ projects must now
>   migrate to libc++ and are recommended to set a deployment target of
>   iOS 7 or later. Besides changing the C++ Standard Library build
>   setting, developers should audit hard-coded linker flags and target
>   dependencies to remove references to libstdc++ (including -lstdc++,
>   -lstdc++.6.0.9, libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd, and libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib). Project dependencies such as static archives that were built against
>   libstdc++ will also need to be rebuilt against libc++. (40885260)

Source: [Release Notes of XCode Beta 2](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10_Beta_2/Xcode_10_Beta_2_Release_Notes.pdf)

Side Note:
 
You need to be logged to access the page.
Link might break in next beta release (URLs change), but it's in the part Developers/Download

XCode 10 being officially released with its [release note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes?language=objc), it's still as such:

> **Building with libstdc++ was deprecated with Xcode 8 and is not
>   supported in Xcode 10 when targeting iOS**. C++ projects must now
>   migrate to libc++ and are recommended to set a deployment target of
>   macOS 10.9 or later, or iOS 7 or later. Besides changing the C++
>   Standard Library build setting, developers should audit hard-coded
>   linker flags and target dependencies to remove references to libstdc++
>   (including -lstdc++, -lstdc++.6.0.9, libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd, and
>   libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib). Project dependencies such as static archives
>   that were built against libstdc++ will also need to be rebuilt against
>   libc++. (40885260)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. yes issue is with C code in Xcode beta version. for now i starting using Xcode 9.4.1 and it is working fine without code rebuilt

Comment: I am also facing same issue in my iOS project. how to resolve this issue in Xcode 10.

Comment: @iSara As said, it has been removed. Did you read the full message? If you static lib was using `stdC++`, then it has to be rebuilt with c++ instead. If it's a third party, notify them, wait for them to do so.

Comment: @Larme I have removed -lstdc++ and added -lc++ library and now i am facing different issue like   "std::ostream::flush()", referenced from:
      -[MAFConsoleLogger logMessage:withLevel:andInfo:] in libMAFLogger.a(MAFConsoleLogger.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)   can you please tell me detail what are the step i need to follow to solve this issue.

Comment: And what is `MAFConsoleLogger`? Apparently you have a static lib name as such. Well, it needs to be rebuilt using `libc++` instead of `libstdc++`. In other words, it was also depending on `libstdc++`, but since it's unsupported now, you have to rebuild it.

Comment: @Larme can you please give details about how to rebuild it  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get that library? Ask the one who built to adapt it.

Comment: @Larme Ok, I will check with them and Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: For me it was simply Deployment Target.  Thanks for posting this.

Comment: I am trying to compile an outdated project that I have downloaded, is there any other answer than "it is deprecated and does not work anymore"?

Answer (score 7):

As said above lstdc++ is removed from Xcode 10. To fix this,

1. Go to Target -> BuildPhases -> Link Binary With Libraries
2. Search for lstdc++ and remove it.
3. Now you might get error in some framework which uses the above said "lstdc++" library. Now either you have to update those framework or remove it so that Xcode can build it successfully.

Answer (score 5):

1. If you are using an external Makefile for building C++ libraries, add

`CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++` your external library Makefile and removed instances of `-stdlib=stdlibc++`

2. If not, ignore the above step, just go to Project>Target>Link Binary with libraries>

   - Remove (-) libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd
   - Add (+) libc++.tbd

Answer (score 1):

This was failing for me when trying to do a `make install`. Instead, I ran `make install -stdlib=libc++`, which did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to compile C program and got `ld: library not found for -lc++`

Because of deprecation as mentioned and the work around that to tell C++ to read from old mac sdk `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk`

```
# adjust your llvm and CLT include paths to match your setup
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include
# then set correct var for compiler lib
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib
```

nice walkthrough at [fixing-cpp-compilation-bugs-for-the-mac-os-catalina-upgrade](https://cmichel.io/fixing-cpp-compilation-bugs-for-the-mac-os-catalina-upgrade/)

Answer (score -2):

Simply go to build settings, Link binary with libraries and there remove this.It resolved my issue.