# library not found for -lstdc++.6.0.9 - Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I want to build my app in Xcode 10.0, I'm getting this error. How I can solve this issue ?

```
library not found for -lstdc++.6.0.9
```

Mac OS version : High Sierra 10.13.6
iOS iPad version : 12.0
Xcode version : 10.0

Regards,
Tuğçe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060596/ld-library-not-found-for-lstdc-6/51060778#51060778

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `Xcode 10` [release](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes) notes,

> Building with libstdc++ was deprecated with Xcode 8 and is not supported in Xcode 10 when targeting iOS. C++ projects must now migrate to libc++ and are recommended to set a deployment target of macOS 10.9 or later, or iOS 7 or later. Besides changing the C++ Standard Library build setting, developers should audit hard-coded linker flags and target dependencies to remove references to libstdc++ (including -lstdc++, -lstdc++.6.0.9, libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd, and libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib). Project dependencies such as static archives that were built against libstdc++ will also need to be rebuilt against libc++. (40885260)

Comment: simply go link binary with libraries in build setting and remove it. Its working for me