# ld: library not found for -lstdc++.6 - Xcode 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode10, lib

> ld: library not found for -lstdc++.6
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

There are quite a bunch of questions like me, 
But I not found any solution for this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060596/ld-library-not-found-for-lstdc-6 ? You also can have a look at the comment on my answer. You have to get rid of libstdc++6, and use libc++. You might have to rebuild your libraries/frameworks in order for them to use libc++ instead of libstdc++.

Comment: @Larme how to rebuild libraries/frameworks?

Comment: So I guess you are not the creator of the lib/frameworks? It's like delivering an .app which isn't supported anymore on that OS version, you have to fix it and rebuilt it. Same here for the lib/Frameworks, ask the author.

Comment: @Larme I search in my project this libstdc ++ 6 but found that I haven't used libstdc ++ 6. So what I need to do?

Comment: Could you the full error message? At least pint point what third party lib/framework you are using that is causing the issue? Also, it should be in link flags, and `-lstdc++6` or something like that.

Comment: I added libc++ and after that show another error.

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBLoginView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Login.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBErrorUtility", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Info.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
objc-class-ref in Info.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Finally. So the issue is with FaceBook. Are you using the up to date framework? I hope that they updated quickly they framework/lib.

Comment: after update facebookSDK getting again this error.  

ld: library not found for -lstdc++.6
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Try copying from previous Xcode version like I did :
**cp -r  /Applications/Xcode_9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/c++
         /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/**

**cp  /Applications/Xcode_9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.*
     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/**