# Mojave Xcode libstdc++ issue when pip installing pyfasttext

Tags: python, xcode, macos, gcc

After I have upgraded to Mojave I got a plethora of problems with Xcode. I have googled the problem that I have but everywhere the instructions are too vague to fix it. Some tell to copy the libstdc++ td files to Applications/Xcode but do not say where to find these files. Some tell to remove libstdc++ files. Some say to copy old files to new files. Some say to amend CXXFLAGS (does not work for me)... etc.

The issue that I have when trying to execute `pip install pyfasttext` in iTerm2 is the following:

`gcc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -iquote . -include src/custom_exit.h -Isrc -I/anaconda3/envs/prometheus/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cysignals -I. -Isrc/variant/include -I/anaconda3/envs/prometheus/include/python3.6m -I/anaconda3/envs/prometheus/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c src/pyfasttext.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/pyfasttext.o -Wno-sign-compare -std=c++0x
    warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]`

What is an easy way to add the `-std=libc++` option to `gcc`? Or is there a better solution?

EDIT:

Installing older command line tools partially solved the issue, until I hit a new one:
`src/pyfasttext.cpp:607:10: fatal error: 'random' file not found
    #include <random>`

Macintosh is so much fun.

Comment: Because it has been removed with XCode 10: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060596/ld-library-not-found-for-lstdc-6/51060778

Comment: yeah I have read that, then why do I keep getting this problem. My version of XCode is 10.