# Unity3D 4.7.2 exported code in Xcode 10.1

Tags: c++, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, xcode10.1

I exported unity3d 4.7.2 game to Xcode 10.1 and its giving compiler error for c++ files.

[image]

How to fix this ?

Here in Unity Forum someone also posted same problem: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1563016/xcode-10-csignal-file-not-found.html?childToView=1572190

**Updates :** Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325326/unity3d-exported-source-c-header-files-not-recognised/53331885#53331885) solution and worked Perfect