# After upgrading to Xcode 10, my Box2D game no longer works

Tags: c++, xcode, box2d, sdl-2, xcode10

It ran fine before, but after upgrading to Xcode 10, my c++ Box2D game no longer runs. Been working on this same project for years, upgraded through lots of Xcode versions without any issues before.

The error:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'memory' file not found in b2Body.h
```

Tried **Clean Build Folder**, no luck. My desktop is on Mojave, my laptop is on High Sierra, so OS version seems irrelevant, but the game ran fine on Xcode 9.

Any other ideas?

Comment: You've tested that you can still build a simple "hello world" program?

Comment: Didn't Xcode deprecate std/libc++? I wonder if this is related. Assuming your error message is referring to `<memory>` or `<memory.h>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ld: library not found for -lstdc++.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060596/ld-library-not-found-for-lstdc-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a relatively simple solution.
Box2D, the physics engine, needed updated to the latest version (likely the developers of the library fixed that std/libc++ issue mentioned above since the last time downloaded it).