# Not able to build openh264 for ios because of libstdc++

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, arm64, openh264

I am trying to build openh264 for ios. I have downloaded the source code from the latest release. then changed the `PREFIX` in makefile to `ios_local`. After that I did `make OS=ios ARCH=arm64` which completed with lot of warning.

After that when I did `sudo make OS=ios ARCH=arm64 install` It exited with error like below

```
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of iOS 7 [-Wdeprecated]
ld: library not found for -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libopenh264.2.0.0.dylib] Error 1
```

After researching it seems like Apple does not support libstdc++ now, so mac os compatible version is libc++ which is supposed to be installed when you install XCode. My XCode version is `Version 10.2.1 (10E1001)` which is more than enough to get this libc++ I think.I am using macOS Mojave. What's going wrong here?

Comment: Where are you including the library? I imagine this will just be a simple switch in a header file?

Comment: sorry did not get you. including means? I am just compiling the given source from the git. only thing I changed in the makefile is PREFIX value. In the Makefile I see this line `STATIC_LDFLAGS=-lstdc++`. Is this line creating the problem?

Comment: Try changing that to `STATIC_LDFLAGS=-libc++` to use the newer library. You will probably have to change the `#include <libc++>` (or simular) in the source too. Can you add a link to the git repo in your question?

Comment: here is the git repo: https://github.com/cisco/openh264/

Comment: Try changing the `LDFLAGS` in the makefile. What happens?

Comment: No, it does not work. I changed. Interesting enough, it still complains about the same problem though the LDFLAG is changed. I guess error is coming from inside not the Makefile.

Comment: Have you got libstdc++ installed? If it's a legacy library it won't come bundled with xcode. The makefile works fine on my machine.

Comment: I dont have libstdc++. XCode 10 does not have it. It's available till XCode 8 which I dont have access to now. Neither macOS Mojave has it.

Comment: Try installing the correct version from source.https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/

Comment: Solved the issue by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060596/ld-library-not-found-for-lstdc-6 . Though there is another problem occurring but that some header file missing issue.