# Having Problems Compiling UltimMC on MacOS Ventura 13

Tags: cmake, makefile, clang, clang++

I was trying to compile UltimMC based on instructions from https://github.com/UltimMC/Launcher/blob/develop/BUILD.md.
I installed Xcode and Java 8 but am not sure if i have installed Qt5 correctly.
I don't have llvm installed.
I also don't know how to set up enviromental variables like in windows and i don't think i have it setup.

I then cloned the repository, made a build folder for it according to said instructions, but when I tried the Cmake commands(copied):

```
cmake \
 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang \
 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ \
 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="$(dirname $PWD)/dist/" \
 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/path/to/Qt5.6/" \
 -DQt5_DIR="/path/to/Qt5.6/" \
 -DLauncher_LAYOUT=mac-bundle \
 -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7 \
 ..
make instal
```

it give me an error:

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 14.0.3.14030022
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ - broken
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/bin/clang++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: '/Users/munirahmadahmadi/launcher/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-r30Xws'
    
    Run Build Command(s): /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E env VERBOSE=1 /usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_62ac3/fast
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_62ac3.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_62ac3.dir/build
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_62ac3.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    /usr/bin/clang++   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_62ac3.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -MF CMakeFiles/cmTC_62ac3.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_62ac3.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /Users/munirahmadahmadi/launcher/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-r30Xws/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    clang: warning: include path for libstdc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
    Linking CXX executable cmTC_62ac3
    /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_62ac3.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/clang++  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/cmTC_62ac3.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_62ac3 
    clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
    ld: library not found for -lstdc++
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[1]: *** [cmTC_62ac3] Error 1
    make: *** [cmTC_62ac3/fast] Error 2
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Please help me if you can.

Comment: The error message `ld: library not found for -lstdc++` probably means that something wrong with your compiler installation. There are many questions about such error, e.g. [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060596/ld-library-not-found-for-lstdc-6),